# Converting Dates in R in both Directions

Tags: r, lubridate

I am trying to convert date objects into a date class using lubridate. These are the following dates in the "wrong" format"

```
wrong_format_date1 <- "01-25-1999"
wrong_format_date2 <- 25012005
wrong_format_date3 <- "2005-05-31"
```

But I would like them in this format:

```
"1999-01-25"
"2005-01-25"
"2005-05-31"
```

Can someone please assist me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Use `parse_date_time()` from `lubridate` where you can define a vector with possible formats so that you get your strings parsed as dates. Here the code:

```
library(lubridate)
#Data
wrong_format_date1 <- "01-25-1999"
wrong_format_date2 <- 25012005
wrong_format_date3 <- "2005-05-31"
#Dataframe
df <- data.frame(v1=c(wrong_format_date1,wrong_format_date2,wrong_format_date3),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Code
df$Date <- as.Date(parse_date_time(df$v1, c("mdY", "dmY","Ymd")))
```

Output:

```
          v1       Date
1 01-25-1999 1999-01-25
2   25012005 2005-01-25
3 2005-05-31 2005-05-31
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! You are always a great help :)